# Avoid filesort in simple filtered ordered query

Tags: mysql, indexing, multi-index

I have a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_values` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`,`user_id`);
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

that I am trying to execute the following simple query:

`select * from user_values where user_id in (20020, 20030) order by id desc;`

I would fully expect this query to 100% use an index (either the (user_id, id) one or the (id, user_id) one) Yet, it turns out that's not the case:

`explain select * from user_values where user_id in (20020, 20030);` yields:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | user_values | NULL | range | user_id | 8 | NULL | 9 | 100.00 | Using index condition; Using filesort |

Why is that the case? How can I avoid a filesort on this trivial query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid the filesort in the query you show.

When you use a range predicate (for example, `IN ( )` is a range predicate), and an index is used, the rows are read in index order. But there's no way for the MySQL query optimizer to guess that reading the rows in index order by `user_id` will guarantee they are also in `id` order. The two `user_id` values you are searching for are potentially scattered all over the table, in any order. Therefore MySQL must assume that once the matching rows are read, an extra step of sorting the result by `id` is necessary.

Here's an example of hypothetical data in which reading the rows by an index on `user_id` will *not* be in `id` order.

| id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20030 |
| 2 | 20020 |
| 3 | 20016 |
| 4 | 20030 |
| 5 | 20020 |

So when reading from an index on `(user_id, id)`, the matching rows will be returned in the following order, sorted by `user_id` first, then by `id`:

| id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 20020 |
| 5 | 20020 |
| 1 | 20030 |
| 4 | 20030 |

Clearly, the result is not in `id` order, so it needs to be sorted to satisfy the `ORDER BY` you requested.

The same kind of effect happens for other type of predicates, for example `BETWEEN`, or `<` or `!=` or `IS NOT NULL`, etc. Every predicate except for `=` is a range predicate.

The only ways to avoid the filesort are to change the query in one of the following ways:

Omit the `ORDER BY` clause and accepting the results in whatever order the optimizer chooses to return them, which could be in `id` order, but only by coincidence.

Change the `user_id IN (20020, 20030)` to `user_id = 20020`, so there is only one matching user_id, and therefore reading the matching rows from the index will already be returned in the `id` order, and therefore the `ORDER BY` is a no-op. The optimizer recognizes when this is possible, and skips the filesort.

Comment: When I change to `user_id = 20020`, `type` changes from `range` to `ref`, `ref` changes from `NULL` to `const`, and `extra` changes from `Using index condition; Using filesort` to `Using filesort`. it seems we did not avoid the filesort?

Comment: I tested this using MySQL 8.0. I do not see `Using filesort`. I don't know which version of MySQL you are using, but the optimizer behavior could be different, or it could be behaving differently based on the data in your table.

Comment: I'm at 8.0.28. Potentially dependent on the data in my db. Thanks for the clarifications. Dumb follow-up question: I assume the engine treats `user_id IN (20020)` as exactly equivalent to `user_id = 20020`?

Comment: I think MySQL 8.0 is clever enough to treat it as an equality predicate if you list a single value. Try using EXPLAIN. If you see `type: ref` then it's treating it as a lookup of a single value, not a range query.

Comment: @BillKarwin - Clever, yes. I noticed that `IN` => `=` optimization long before 8.0.  (I don't remember when it was added.)

Comment: I don't remember when it was added either. I only tested 8.0 for this question.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will most likely use index for the query (unless the user_id's in the query covers most of the rows).

The "filesort" happens in memory (it's really not a filesort), and is used to sort the found rows based on the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: When it's only sorting 9 row, it will be in memory, but when you have a lot of rows, it will probably a temp file.

Comment: @Luuk - If there had been a `TEXT` column, it would necessarily be done via a temp table, which would be on disk (baring caching).  Only if no `TEXT` (etc) and "few enough" rows will it necessarily be sorted in  RAM.

Comment: Ok, for the complete story: [10.2 How MySQL Does Sorting (filesort)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/filesort.html), which refers to: [8.2.1.16 ORDER BY Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot avoid a "sort" in this case.

There were about 9 rows to sort, so it could not have taken long.

How long did the query take?  Probably only a few milliseconds, so who cares?

"Filesort" does not necessarily mean that a "file" was involved.  In many queries the sort is done in RAM.

Do you use `id` for anything other than to have a `PRIMARY KEY` on the table?  If not, then this will help a small amount.  (The speed-up won't be indicated in `EXPLAIN`.)

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`id`),  -- to avoid secondary lookups
  KEY `id` (`id`);   -- to keep auto_increment happy
```